# 3d input for Dense Layer Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Is there any example of how Keras `Dense` layer handles `3D` input.

The documentation explains the following:

> If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense
> computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the
> last axis of the inputs and axis 1 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot).

But I could not understand the internal `matrix calculation`

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
sample_3d_input = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(4,3,2)))
dense_layer  = Dense(5)
op = dense_layer(sample_3d_input)
```

based on the documentation for a `3D` input of shape `(m,d0,d1)`, the shape of `Layer's weight_matrix (or) kernel` will have the shape `(d1, units) which is (2,5)` in this case. But I don't understand how the op is calculated to have the shape `(m,d0, units)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reproduce the operation on your own...

```
sample_3d_input = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(4,3,2)))
dense_layer  = Dense(5)

op = dense_layer(sample_3d_input)
W, b = dense_layer.get_weights()

manual_op = tf.tensordot(sample_3d_input, W, axes=[[2],[0]]) + b
```

Comparison:

```
>>> tf.reduce_all(op == manual_op).numpy()
... True
```